# How to set parameter in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am unable to set parameter in a JavaScript function,below is my code:

```
var product=<?php echo json_encode($product); ?>;
            var uniqueid=<?php echo json_encode($shop_uniqueid); ?>;
            var shop_photo=<?php echo json_encode($photo); ?>;
            var price=<?php echo json_encode($price); ?>;
            var author=<?php echo json_encode($author); ?>;

            //onmouseover='this.width='someWidth'; this.height='someHeight'" onmouseout="this.width='originalWidth'; this.height='originalHeight''

            $('#'+<?php echo $count; ?>).html("<div class='div1'><img class='shopperspic' src='b2b/Product Images/"+uniqueid+"/"+shop_photo+"' alt='' /></div><div class='div2'><span style='font-weight:bold;'>"+product+"</span></div><div class='div3'>By: <span style='text-decoration:underline'>"+author+"</span></div><div class='in_div'><div class='div_price'><img src='header/images/rupee.png' />"+price+"</div><div>|QTY<select><option value='1'>1</option><option value='2'>2</option><option value='3'>3</option><option value='4'>4</option><option value='5'>5</option></select>&nbsp;<input type='button' id='add_"+div.id+"' value='Add to cart' onClick='add_to_cart()'/></div></div>");
```

I want to pass parameter `var product` in `onClick='add_to_cart()'`

Comment: `onClick='add_to_cart(" + product + ")'`

Comment: I have tried it but function is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php variable should be in `single quotes` when you are assigning it to javascript variable so you should write like this.

```
var product = '<?php echo json_encode($product); ?>';
```

Comment: yes that worked for me,but now the problem is that when i am displaying product on homepage it is showig like this: "xyz" but it should not.

Comment: so how you want it to display ?

Comment: It should display just as xyz not "xyz",as it was showing before i put var product='<?php echo json_encode($product); ?>';

Comment: can you show me that what is assigned to $product and how ? and also tell me exact final html code of button

Comment: yeah sure here the file on the dropbox you can take:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqt6ox8rg7aqbr1/prob.txt?dl=0

Comment: i didn't see any script tag around js and jquery code :( so how is this working for you ?

Comment: i have given the relevant code for your reference in which i am getting stuck.

Comment: by the way remove `json_encode` function from the product variable so may it fix the problem just write `var product = '<?php echo $product; ?>'`

Comment: no i have tried it that way too but doing so will remove all the divs.

I have tried like this and its working:

var product1=product.replace('"','');
var product1=product1.replace('"','');

and replaced product with product1 :)

Comment: hmm try this `var product= JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($product)?>');` it should work

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
<input type='button' id='add_"+div.id+"' value='Add to cart' onClick='add_to_cart(" + product + ")'/>
```

Comment: i used it but it is interpreted as <input type="button" id="add_5" value="Add to cart" onclick="add_to_cart(XYZ)"> and function is:

<script type="text/javascript">
 function add_to_cart(a)
 {
  alert(a);
 }
 </script>

Comment: shouldnt be there " " around XYZ?

Answer (score -1):

If you set it as a var, you can just use this:

```
onClick='add_to_cart(product)'
```